# Ошибка отображения стилей в Safari

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, webkit, слайдер

[Сайт](http://silentlife.ru/), на котором слайдер не отображается. В Хроме и других браузерах отображаются кнопки и изображения. А в Сафари(5.7.1) нет. Как это исправить?

[image: Нормальное отображение]

Вот здесь скриншот, как сайт отображается в Chrome.

А вот то же самое в Safari,

[image: Отображение в Safari]

```
 .box-text{padding: 10px 50px 30px;}
.box-text .title {margin-bottom: 10px;font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
.box-text .title h3{font-size: 37px; font-weight:800;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;}
.box-text .title span{font-size: 24px; font-weight:800;color: #000;text-transform: uppercase;margin: 40px 0 20px;display: block;}

.box-text .content{margin: 20px 0;}
.box-text .speed-inf{margin: 10px 0 20px;font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;}
.box-text .speed-inf strong{display: block; font-size: 35px; color: #000;line-height: 47px;}
.box-text .speed-inf p{margin: 0;font-weight: 700;font-size: 14px;color: #444;}

.flex-box  .box-image {background-repeat: no-repeat;background-position: center center;background-size: cover;display: block;z-index: 1;width: 100%;height: 100%;}
.flex-box .f-right{order: 2;} flexbox – display: box;

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1200px) {
    .box-text{padding: 60px;}
}

@media(min-width:768px){
    .flex-box {
      flex-direction: row;
      -webkit-flex-direction: row;
        -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
      display: flex;
      display: -webkit-flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
    }
    .box-text.text-right{text-align: right;}
    .box-text.text-right .content:before,
    .box-text.text-right .content:after{right: 0;}
}
@media(max-width:767px){
    .box-text{text-align: center;}
    .box-text .content:before,
    .box-text .content:after{right: 47%;}
    .flex-box  .box-image {height: 430px;width: 100%;}
}
```

Сам слайдер вроде бы написан на JQuery. Но я не думаю, что ошибка связана со скриптом.

Comment: Вам обязательно надо такой старый сафари?

Comment: Ну, просто проверял кроссбраузерность так. Знакомый попросил решить проблему, и он проверял на сафари этой версии. Я ж в эппловском не разбираюсь, и только что узнал, что это старая версия браузера. Теперь вопросы отпали сами собой.

Comment: На чуть более новом Safari 8 (2014 год) те же проблемы, кстати. Разбираться или нет — зависит от того, насколько старые версии Safari нужно поддерживать

Comment: В Safari 8 я нашёл две проблемы: во-первых, не поддерживается CSS-свойство `order`, во-вторых, `height: 100%` некорректно работает внутри flex-контейнера. Судя по ответу, в Safari 11 это всё уже исправлено

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple прекратили поддержку Safari для Windows в 2012, возможно, какое-то свойство, которое вы используете, не поддерживается (сложно сказать не имея браузера под рукой).

В Safari 11.1.1 на Mac всё работает корректно.

Comment: Можете скинуть скриншот того, как он отображается на Маке?

Comment: @ZeretteСompany, да, пожалуйста — https://jmp.sh/0NDJt6i